# Why is there inconsistent spacing between two similarly styled elements, and how can I make them consistent?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, whitespace

http://bit.ly/jEiZ2Z

If you click on the "7" and "8", you'll be selecting an arrival and end date.

The vertical spacing ( white space / border ) is inconsistent with this:

http://bit.ly/lem5aI

I'm referring to the bottom white "border":

[image]

It's off by a pixel or two. I want it to look like the first link.

In the latter link, you need to actually click on any of the textfields in the console ( eg arrival, departure ) to get the calendar to show up.

Stylistically it seems exactly the same, including the styles of outer parents, etc. I'm pretty sure it's something being inconsistently inherited, or perhaps it's whitespace literally in the HTML. ( I've had a long 20+ hr day so my eyes are not fresh ).

Would be great if someone could try spotting this.

In addition, it looks much more off ( more than 1 pixel ) in IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be caused by this, inside `layout.css`:

```
div#content table td,
div#content table th { vertical-align: top; }
```

Testing with Chrome 12, if I toggle that off on one of your `<td day="44" ..>` elements, it's fixed.

Your "working" page does not have that CSS.

Comment: my god, that's what overtime does to you... kills your eyes.. thanks!